# Kivy Android Sqlite3 fts app crashes with a "no such module" error

Tags: android, sqlite, crash, full-text-search, kivy

im building my first app, it include a small DB with sqlite3 using FTS. I can push my app in my phone and it works, however it crashes when i do a FTS query on the DB. I get this:

```
12-30 15:37:02.861 28307 28337 I python  : Error no such module: fts3:
```

The app works well before its compiled, so fts gets forgotten during compilation i guess?

Any idea how to fix that? Does Kivy actually support FTS?

im almost there! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got this to work with the help of @KeeWeeUsr

1- I wasnt using the correct command on buildozer. android instead of android_new , this created the correct folders with the correct sqlite3 recipe in which FTS4 is enabled by default.

2- Even if sqlite3 was added the buildozer.spec , i needed to remove sqlite3 from ALL blacklist.txt files in my project (created after the first build)

FTS4 now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If FTS isn't pure Python (C extension or something), then it needs a [recipe](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/), otherwise you only need to mention it in the `requirements` when you build your app.

Also, using sdl2 (`android new`) bootstrap is recommended, as PyGame is getting to the background and isn't really maintained since the switch to sdl2 on android.

Comment: Hi, I added sqlite3 to the requirement but how can I add fts specifically? fts or fts3 didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @Atoms You need to add the same name to requirements as you did with `pip install`. If it doesn't work, it's most likely a not pure Python package, therefore you'll need to write a recipe.

Comment: @KeeWeeUsr Ok so i solved my recipe.sh problem. It was me not using android_new but just android. Now im using android_new and i can see that the recipe for sqlite enables fts4 by default. However, it gives me a "Attribute error: context objct has no attribute hostpython" which i can solve by adding python2 in my requirements (buildozer.spec). the app compiles succesfully, but then "no module sqlite3" when i start the app on my android phone. I tried to move the requirement arounds but it had no effect. Any ideas? i know im close to solve this ahah.     Thanks!

Comment: @Atoms you need to put sqlite3 to requirements too.

Comment: @KeeWeeUsr I did sorry i didnt mention it. sqlite3,python2,kivy . Now im readin about blacklist.txt. Do i need to add sqlite3 to android.p4a_whitelist = in .spec?

Comment: Ok i got sqlite to work. No i have another problem but its sqlite related. thanks for your help :D